# Webpack not showing index.html in browser

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am using webpack to watch changes in my code. The code compiles successfully, but I cannot see anything by going to browser.

package.json

```js
   "dev:server": "webpack server --hot",
   "prod:build": "webpack"
```

Project structure

```js
- webpack.config.js
- package.json
- src/
  - index.hbs
  - sass/
  - js/
```

webpack.config.json

```
module.exports = {
entry: {
  "main-page": "./src/js/index.js",
},
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.[name].[contenthash].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
    publicPath: "dist/",
  },
  mode: "production",
  module: ,
    optimization:,
      plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin({
          cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns: ["**/*"],
        }),
        new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
          chunks: ["main-page"],
          template: "src/index.hbs",
        }),
      ],
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added following in webpack.config.js and it worked.

```
mode: "development", //change in production
devServer: {
  // remove in production
  contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
  index: "index.html",
},
```